# Svelte: Dynamic Tailwind-Class from Variable

Tags: binding, svelte, tailwind-css

How can I apply a tailwind class, if another var is true ... the follwoing does not seem to work.

### This works

```
<script>
    let svgColor = 'text-red-400'
    
</script>
    
<p class="{svgColor}">Test</p>
```

### But this does not

```
<script>
    let svgColor = 'text-red-400'
    let svgVisible = true;
</script>

<p class="{svgVisible ? {svgColor} : ''}">Test</p>
```

Comment: instead of using {curly braces} for the variable, use 'single quotes' since you are already inside an expression.
{svgVisible ? 'svgColor' : ''}

Comment: I just tried. It does not work. ... and would that not just apply a class named 'svgColor' and not the value of var svgColor? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By wrapping the svgColor with the curly braces you are effectively making an object with the prop svgColor.

The correct syntax would be:

```html
<p class={svgVisible ? svgColor : ''}>Test</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is it. Makes sense now, with curly braces now. Thanks for the explanation, too.